# List views : Addting a new standard field to multiple Lead List views

Tags: apex, soql, list-view, admin

We have around 100 Lead List views for Lead. I need to add a new field (company) to be displayed in all the list views. Instead of manually editing each list view and adding the company field one at a time, is there a way to mass update(add) the company field for all the list views for the Lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practical way using the front end. However, if you are skilled in the use of the [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_deploying_ant.htm) (or you're ready to learn it), you could create a package.xml and download the object in question. Then edit the object file (which contains the Listview definitions) and reupload.

A second way, as @BrianMansfield mentions below, is to simply set up your project in Mavens/Atom/Eclipse and configure it to download object metadata. Then open the project, make the edits, and save the file. I've done this in Atom/Mavens before.

Comment: This is the fastest way - although it would likely be faster for OP to create a project in mavensmate or other lightweight IDE rather than set up Ant, etc

Comment: Good point, Brian. I will add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I have downloaded the object metadata in force.com IDE in Eclipse and will be making the changes there. It would be great to have a tool or inbuilt functionality where such modifications were made easier in Salesforce.

Comment: Reshmi, that one is up to you to take to SFDC. :) If this answer helped you, mark it as "Accepted" so others can benefit.